# Mule Anypoint Studio Passing in JSON and working in Java

Tags: java, json, xml, anypoint-studio

I'm not too familiar with Anypoint and we will probably only use this program once,  I've looked at tutorials on the website but I feel I can't find one that demonstrates the task we have.  Basically we are trying to read a JSON file that will be sent to the software, from there we want to use JAVA to read/alter the contents into a desired XML formatting.  Finally we then send back or redirect the XML results.

1: I am trying to accept a JSON file from a HTTP POST, I believe I have accomplished this part by using the tutorials and an HTTP element with metadata attached representing the JSON format that may come.  Using postman to send the json data as well.

2:  From here is where I start to get completely confused.  I am wondering what I would need to do in order to pass the data into a Java class object to read the JSON file and begin using Java code (getters/setters) instead of the Anypoint interface in order to start designing the xml layout.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the next step is for you to define a model class(with getter/setter), which would represent your json file contents. Since you have already the POST part, the next thing you would do is to use JSON to Object Transformer which the model is injected in.

`<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.alexfrndz.Person" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>`

After adding the transformer, you could use a mule custom transformer,
   Here is the custom transformer.

```
package com.alexfrndz;

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

public class PersonTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

   @Override
   public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
       Person person = (Person) message.getPayload();
       //Do your transformation hear
    return null;
    }

}
```

Here is how you implement it,

```
 <custom-transformer class="com.alexfrndz.PersonTransformer" doc:name="PersonTransformer"/>
```

Hope this will help you.